# Integral of a periodic function divided by period

Tags: calculus, integration

can someone please help me prove the following?

If it is given that:  $x(t)=x(t+T)$

We define: $$\frac{1}{T}\int_T x(t) dt  = \frac{1}{T} \int_{\frac{-T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(t) dt $$

Prove that for every $k$ : $$\frac{1}{T}\int_T x(t) dt = \frac{1}{kT}\int_{kT} x(t) dt $$

Cheers

Comment: Please check your limits of integration.

Comment: @ Ajay: $\frac{1}{T}\int_T x(t) dt $ is defined(!) to be $\frac{1}{T} \int_{\frac{-T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(t) dt.$

Comment: The notation on LHS used for definition is confusing. Normally $\int_Tx(t)dt$ denotes $\int\mathbf{1}_T(t)x(t)dt$ where $T$ is a set.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{a}^{a+kT}x(t)dt=\int_{0}^{kT}x(t)dt=k\int_0^{T}x(t)dt$$

(The first step can easily be verified by showing that $\frac{dI}{da}=0$ and the second step arises from the periodicity of the function)

Comment: don't forget that $k$ can be any number not only an integer, so that $x(a+kT)-x(a)$ is not necessarily 0

Comment: @SammyApsel That doesn't seem correct, if $k$ can be anything, then $kT$ can be anything, so basically what you're saying is that $\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{-\frac{\alpha}{2}}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}x(t)dt$ is constant, which is obviously not always correct, take $\cos x$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac{1}{T} \int_{\frac{-T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(t) dt$ use the substitution $s=Kt$ to get $\frac{1}{kT}\int_{kT} x(t) dt.$

Comment: if you do that shouldn't you get: $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{K}{s}$?